# why mongodb auto add key for a array element?

Tags: php, mongodb

below code will insert a document, and the document in mongodb will be look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5510d1ad7f8b9aaf318b457b"), "0" : "a", "1" : "b", "2" : "c", "d" : [ NumberLong(1), NumberLong(2), NumberLong(3), NumberLong(4) ], "tags" : [ "mongodb", "mysql", "redis" ] }
```

why the mongodb **auto add** some key for me: "0", "1", "3"...， but **tags** values don't?

```
<?php 
$doc = array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd' => array(1,2,3,4),
    "tags" => array('mongodb', 'mysql', 'redis')
);

$client = new MongoClient();
$client->d->test->insert($doc);

$cursor = $client->d->test->find();

foreach($cursor as $item)
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo json_encode($item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func)

> An array can be created using the array() language construct. It takes any number of comma-separated key => value pairs as arguments.

If you don't specify the key value which optional, PHP will use the increment of the largest previously used integer key. So `print_r($doc)` will display below output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [d] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => mongodb
            [1] => mysql
            [2] => redis
        )

)
```

That being said.

> Why the mongodb auto add some key for me: "0", "1", "3" but tags values don't?

MongoDB use the keys as fields in your document and since you did not specify key for `'a'` ,`'b'` and `'c'` integers keys   used as fields names instead and this is not what you want.

Quoting the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.insert.php#mongo.tutorial.insert)

> Note that you can have nested arrays and objects. The driver will always store an associative array as an object in the database. A numerically indexed array is stored as an array in case the keys start at 0 and are not interrupted, and as an object if the array keys don't start at 0 or have gaps (ie: 0, 1, 4, 5).

Comment: but the document in the collection does not have key: 0,1,2 in the tags value.why?